# WooCommerce Booking email template

Tags: php, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm trying to customize an email template for WooCommerce and we're using the WooCommerce booking plugin. I'm trying to display the attributes in the email but I'm having difficulty doing so.

I tried to use `get_the_terms($product->ID,'pa_attribute')` but it doesn't seem to work. I think it's because the email template is not able to get the product ID. The only ID that outputs for me is the `$order->ID` which is not really what I need.

How I can get the resource product ID of an order in WooCommerce Booking email?

Comment: If the object $product isn't available to the email template, you'll need to figure out some way to pass the data to the template from the caller.  Is there some array (or other structure) of variables for the template to use?

Comment: If you have the order ID, you can get the order object. `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` If you have the order object, you can get an array of all the products purchased with the [`$order->get_items()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L1118-L1150) method.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks. I got the array values returned for the `$order->get_items()` . Now my problem is, how do I get a specific value from the array? It's like an array within an array within an array. Sorry but I'm a total beginner at PHP. 

Array returns something like this:
`Array([16]=> Array([name]=>somename))`

I tried doing `var_dump($output[0]['name']);` but it just returns NULL.

Comment: I just realized that the array values returnes doesn't seem to have commas in between the values.

`Array ( [16] => Array ( 
[name] => VILLA D'ESTE & HADRIAN'S VILLA TIVOLI DAY TOUR 
[type] => line_item )) `

The name and type doesn't have a comma between then. Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you try editing your question to elaborate on what, specifically you are trying to do? Where are you trying to add the attribute terms? I have a feeling we're not approaching the answer correctly.

Comment: In the complete order email template of woocommerce. I can't use `get_the_terms($product->ID,'pa_attribute')` because I'm unable to get the product ID. The code that you gave me with `$order->get_terms()` works and has the product ID in one of the array values. I can't seem to get the value though. I'm planning to use the data that I get from the array to put in the get_the_terms function. :(

Comment: Got it sorted out. Thanks for the help @helgatheviking. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed. Thanks to @helgatheviking. Here's my code.

```
    `$order = wc_get_order( $order->id );  $order = $order->get_items();  $productid = $orderdd[16]["product_id"];  $attdata = wp_get_post_terms($productid,'pa_attributeslug');  foreach ( $attdata as $data ) {  echo $data->name;}`
```